# Is VPN a layer 3 concept?

Tags: vpn

From Tanenbaum's Computer Network

> This demand soon led to the invention of **VPNs (Virtual Private Networks)**,
>   which are overlay networks on top of public networks but with most of the properties of private networks.
>
> **One popular approach** is to build VPNs directly over the Internet. A
>   common design is to equip each office with a firewall and create
>   tunnels through the Internet between all pairs of offices. ...  When
>   the system is brought up, each pair of firewalls has to negotiate the
>   parameters of its SA, including the services, modes, algorithms, and
>   keys. If IPsec is used for the tunneling, it is possible to aggregate
>   all traffic between any two pairs of offices onto a single
>   authenticated, encrypted SA, thus providing in- tegrity control,
>   secrecy, and even considerable immunity to traffic analysis. Many
>   firewalls have VPN capabilities built in. Some ordinary routers can do
>   this as well, but since firewalls are primarily in the security
>   business, it is natural to have the tunnels begin and end at the
>   firewalls, providing a clear separation between the company and the
>   Internet. **Thus, firewalls, VPNs, and IPsec with ESP in tunnel mode are
>   a natural combination and widely used in practice.** Once the SAs have
>   been established, traffic can begin flowing. **To a router within the
>   Internet, a packet traveling along a VPN tunnel is just an ordinary
>   packet.** The only thing unusual about it is the presence of the IPsec
>   header after the IP header, but since these extra headers have no
>   effect on the forwarding process, the routers do not care about this
>   extra header.
>
> **Another approach** that is gaining popularity is to have the ISP set up
>   the VPN. Using MPLS (as discussed in Chap. 5), paths for the VPN
>   traffic can be set up across the ISP network between the company
>   offices. These paths keep the VPN traffic separate from other Internet
>   traffic and can be guaranteed a certain amount of bandwidth or other
>   quality of service.

1. Is VPN a layer 3 or 5 concept?  (seems to me yes?)
2. Do both approaches in the quote to build VPNs are layer 3
   approaches? (Seems to me yes, because  the technologies involved to built VPNs seem to be layer 3)
3. Does [openvpn](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openvpn.html.en) use the server-client model and therefore a layer
   5 approach to build VPNs? How do a openvpn  server and client work
   together to build a VPN? I can't figure it out based on the two
   approaches in the book.
4. Similar questions for [SSH VPN](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH_VPN) to those for openvpn.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are layer-2 and layer-3 VPNs. "VPN" is a term used for a tunnel combined with encryption.

A tunneling interface encapsulates an inner packet (or frame) in an outer packet. This inner packet is then transported to the far tunnel end, according to the outer packet, and decapsulated again. For the inner packet the tunnel looks like a direct connection, regardless of the path of the outer packet.

Tunneling somewhat defies the strict OSI layering. Usually, layer-3 packets are tunneled over layer 3 (IPsec) or layer 4 (TCP or UDP). An L3 tunnel routes between two networks.

When layer-2 frames are tunneled, the networks are bridged together.

OpenVPN uses SSL VPN over UDP or TCP (layer 4) with SSL encryption. It can tunnel either L2 or L3. SSH has an inherent tunneling mechanism for arbitrary connections including port forwarding.

[edit] Note that we're using OSI layer numbers here (as far as applicable), so your "layer 5" application layer is usually refered to as layer 7.

Comment: Thanks. "OpenVPN uses SSL VPN over UDP or TCP (layer 4) with SSL encryption". Do you mean the protocols from top to bottom are: VPN, SSL, UDP/TCP?

Comment: VPN is not a protocol. OpenVPN uses UDP or TCP with SSL and tunnels IP within.

Comment: Thanks. Are protocols from top to bottom (one encapsulate the one below) are: IP, SSL, UDP/TCP?

Comment: If you insist: IP encapsulated in UDP/SSL over IP is the most common variant (OpenVPN also supports L2 VPN, SSL is more or less a TCP or UDP option).

Comment: In L2 VPN, what protocols are encapsulate and how are they encapulated?

Comment: Google L2TP for a L2 type VPN

Comment: @slebetman If I can figure that out by googling, I would not ask here. Thank you in avdance for understanding.

Comment: @Zac67  Another question. OpenVPN is implemented based on the application layer (layer 5) Are the two approaches for building VPNs in Tanenbaum's book (one by firewall, and the other by MPLS) both based on layer 3?

Comment: @tim An L2 VPN tunnels/encapsulates L2 frames (e.g. Ethernet). Again, OpenVPN sits (if you insist as application-layer protocol) on top of UDP or TCP (as transport-layer protocols). These sit on top of IP (as network-layer protocol). IP possibly sits on top of Ethernet (as data-link-layer and physical-layer protocols). OpenVPN tunnels/encapsulates L2 frames or L3 packets, depending on configuration.

Comment: There are two approaches for building VPNs in Tanenbaum's book (one by firewall, and the other by MPLS). The one by firewall uses IPsec, and what protocal's message is the payload of an IPsec message?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the follow up questions. The last one "VPN is not a protocol." Is VPN an application instead? Why is VPN not a protocol? How can I tell if something is a protocol or not?

Comment: @Tim Often, not being able to figure something out is not due to the inability to read. It is due to not knowing where to start. Googling L2TP will give you a starting point and enough research material to understand what L2 tunneling looks like. No answer here can even possibly be as comprehensive as the articles out there about L2TP. People tell you **what to google** not to imply that you cannot do research but to genuinely try to help you.

Comment: @Tim I'd call VPN a general concept. There are many ways to do it and countless protocols.

Answer (score 5):

> Is VPN a layer 3 or 5 concept? (seems to me yes?)

It's both. And it's others. The VPN software is layers 5-7, whilst commonly L3 routing is used to direct packets trough the VPN. Note that layers generally break down above layer 3; there's fuzzy boundaries.

> Does openvpn use the server-client model and therefore a layer 5 approach to build VPNs?

Yes, but the result is a layer 3 tunnel. You have to differentiate between the tunnel and the software that builds it, and how traffic trough the tunnel is handled.

Note that OpenVPN may run in L2 mode as well, commonly known as `tap` device.

Comment: Thanks. WHat is the tunnelling protocol provided by openvpn?

Comment: Many. As L2 tunnel? Whatever you care to throw at it.

Answer (score 3):

Layer 3 VPN (L3VPN) is a type of VPN mode that is built and delivered on OSI layer 3 networking technologies. The entire communication from the core VPN infrastructure is forwarded using layer 3 virtual routing and forwarding techniques. Layer 3 VPN is also known as virtual private routed network (VPRN).